# AngularJS ng-repeat group by date formatting issues

Tags: angularjs

I have a JSON array that I need to group by the date.
so using angular-filter I created this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in controller.collections.data | groupBy: 'plannedCollectionDate'">

    Group name: {{ key | date: 'fullDate' }}

    <li ng-repeat="item in value">
        item: {{ item }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

which is fine, but what I actually want to generate is a table. I tried this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in controller.collections.data | groupBy: 'plannedCollectionDate' | orderBy: 'plannedCollectionDate'">

    {{ key | date: 'fullDate' }}

    <table class="table table-hover table-light">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="collection in value | filter: controller.filter" ng-click="controller.select(collection)" ng-class="{ active: controller.isSelected(collection), warning: collection.status.id === 2, success: collection.status.id === 4, danger: collection.status.id === 5 }">
                <td>
                    <div>{{ collection.supplierName }} {{ collection.description }}</div>
                    <div>to be collected by {{ collection.customerName }}</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a ui-sref=".collect({ selected: [collection]})">{{ collection.status.name }}</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="controller.delete(collection.id)">
                        <span class="fa fa-close"></span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

which again works fine, it generates a table for each group though. What I would prefer is to have one table with a header for the **groupBy** dates and then trs for the inner repeat. I imagine I have to do something like **ng-repeat-start** but I can't get it to work.

Has anyone got any idea how to do what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this wasn't too hard to figure out.
I just changed the way I was thinking about the headers.

This is my solution:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-light">
    <tbody ng-repeat="group in controller.collections.data | groupBy: 'plannedCollectionDate' | toArray: true | orderBy: '-plannedCollectionDate'">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">
                {{ group.$key | date: 'fullDate' }}
            </th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="collection in group | filter: controller.filter" ng-click="controller.select(collection)" ng-class="{ active: controller.isSelected(collection), warning: collection.status.id === 2, success: collection.status.id === 4, danger: collection.status.id === 5 }">
            <td>
                <div>{{ collection.supplierName }} {{ collection.description }}</div>
                <div>to be collected by {{ collection.customerName }}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a ui-sref=".collect({ selected: [collection]})">{{ collection.status.name }}</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="controller.delete(collection.id)">
                    <span class="fa fa-close"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```